# Mocha Test, Yeoman, Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mocha.js

I created a project with the generator for Chrome extensions. Below is a representation of my folder structure.

```
my-wonderful-chrome-extension
   app
     scripts
        common.js
   test
     index.html
     spec
        test.js
```

I want to test the `common.js`. My understanding of Mocha is that I should have a `index.html` file like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Mocha Spec Runner</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/mocha/mocha.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mocha"></div>
        <script src="bower_components/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
        <script>    
            mocha.setup('bdd');
            mocha.reporter('html');
        </script>
        <script src="bower_components/chai/chai.js"></script>
        <script>
            var assert = chai.assert;
            var expect = chai.expect;
            var should = chai.should();
        </script>

        <!-- include source files here... -->
        <script src="../app/scripts/common.js"></script>

        <!-- include spec files here... -->
        <script src="spec/test.js"></script>

        <script>mocha.run()</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The test file (`test.js`) looks like this:

```js
/* global describe, it */
describe('Find the root recipe node', function () {
    it('Should not find an elem in null dom', function () {
        console.log(dds_hmr.findRecipeRoot);
    });
});
```

The `common.js` file looks like this:

```js
var dds_hmr = {};
dds_hmr.findRecipeRoot = function (elem) {
    if (elem && elem.hasAttribute("itemtype")
            && elem.getAttribute("itemtype") === "http://schema.org/Recipe") {
        return [elem];
    } else {
        var result = [];
        if (elem) {
            for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var child = dds_hmr.findRecipeRoot(elem.childNodes[i]);
                result.concat(child);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
1) Find the root recipe node Should not find an elem in null dom:
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dds_hmr
        at http://localhost:9000/spec/test.js:4
        at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js:4263
        at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js:4635
        at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js:4694
        at next (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js:4561)
        at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js:4570
        at next (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js:4514)
        at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js:4538
        at timeslice (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js:5531)
```

What do I need to do to get the test to reference the code in the `common.js` file?

Comment: For those down voting, please explain your issue with either the question or the answers. As far as I can tell this is a model of both.

Comment: I think the downvotes accumulated before you edited the question with proper information. Same with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the solution lies in the Grunt configuration (makes sense). In the `connect` key for the grunt server there is a `test` key. Under the property `options` there is another property `base`. Add `'app'` to that list. This will include the app directory at test execution time. From there the trick is to change the script include in the `index.html` from

```html
<!-- include source files here... -->
<script src="../app/scripts/common.js"></script>
```

to

```html
<!-- include source files here... -->
<script src="scripts/common.js"></script>
```

**Update: Added the Grunt section**

```js
// Grunt server and debug server setting
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    livereload: 35729,
    // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
    hostname: 'localhost'
  },
  chrome: {
    options: {
      open: false,
      base: [
        '<%= config.app %>'
      ]
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      open: false,
      base: [
        'test',
        'app',
        '<%= config.app %>'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```